# Django favicon.ico in development?

Tags: django, favicon

How can I serve favicon.ico in development? I could add a route in my urlconf, but I don't want that route to carry over to the production environment. Is there a way to do this in local_settings.py?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#django.views.static.serve):

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns("",
    # Your stuff goes here
) + static('/', document_root='static/')
```

There doesn't appear to be a way to serve a single static file, but at least this helper function is a wrapper which only works when DEBUG = True.

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way would be to just put it in your static directory with your other static media, then specify its location in your html:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'images/favicon.ico' %}"/>
```

My old answer was:

You can set up an entry in your `urls.py` and just check if `debug` is true.  This would keep it from being served in production. I think you can just do similar to static media.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^favicon.ico$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/path/to/favicon'}),
    )
```

You also could just serve the favicon from your view.:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_image(request):
    image_data = open("/home/moneyman/public_html/media/img/favicon.ico", "rb").read()
    return HttpResponse(image_data, content_type="image/png")
```

Comment: I had marked this as correct, but on closer inspection it doesn't actually work. django.views.static.serve will only serve directories, not single files.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

...

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(r'/favicon.ico', document_root='static/favicon.ico')
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
from django import conf
from django.conf.urls import static

...

if conf.settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static.static(
        r"/favicon.ico", document_root=conf.settings.STATIC_ROOT / "favicon.ico"
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can create your own loader.py file, which loads settings you want to override.
Loading this file should look like this:

```
try:
    execfile(os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, 'loader.py'))
except:
    pass
```

and be added at the end of settings.py.
This settings should not be commited into production server, only should appear on development machines. If you are using git, add loader.py into .gitignore.